# There was no channel actively listening at .This is often caused by an incorrect address URI

Tags: wcf, rest

When I am calling the wcf service from RestClient getting the error:

[EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://localhost/Test/TestService.svc/TestMethod&#39;. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web> 
  <system.serviceModel>     
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="http" port="80" />
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TestService.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="TestService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TestService.ITestService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">

        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Test/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Have searched many similar issue but not resolving, Kindly help..

Here is the service code:

```
 namespace TestService
{

    [ServiceContract]
        public interface ITestService 
        {
            [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            string TestMethod();
        }
}

    namespace TestService
{
    public class TestService: ITestService 
        {
            public string TestMethod()
            {
                return "Hello";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Basically this error only means that you can't connect to a server. For example firewall block. incorrect configuration. So on 
http://localhost/Test/ seems to be not a service to which you can connect with the given configurations. So Could you also provide the server code ?

Comment: There is no firewall and  I am testing the service in the local system. Both the server and client are on the same system. When I browsing the svc file from IIS it's displaying as expected.

Comment: Yes but how is it coded ? It seems like it is not running or has a configuration that is not compatible with y our client,. But without seeing the service code it is impossible to tell that.

Comment: @BoasEnkler please look into the service code

Comment: Fix your code to show the name of the class implementing `ITestService`.

Comment: Also show how the client is calling the service.

Comment: @jstreet Thats a typing mistake. I am using Chrome Extention RestClient to call the service

Comment: Looks like your URI has an extra `Test` in it: `http://localhost/Test/TestService.svc`. Try `http://localhost/TestService.svc` instead.

Comment: From what i see online, you probably should be using `webHttpBinding`, and also create a `<webHttp/>` behavior for your end point.

Comment: Yes and I also need to add the UriTemplate="Test"

Answer (score 1):

add UriTemplate = "Test/"

```
namespace TestService
    {

        [ServiceContract]
            public interface ITestService 
            {
                [OperationContract,WebInvoke(Method = "POST",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "Test/")] 
                string TestMethod();
            }
    }
```

config:

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      </system.web> 
      <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttp"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" >
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType = "None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="http" port="80" />
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TestService.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TestService.ITestService" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">

        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```